# DateTime formatting in SSRS ReportViewer always uses en-US?

Tags: winforms, localization, reporting-services

I'm having a show-stopping issue with the ReportViewer component that's part of SSRS. I'm working on a WinForms application and have a couple of local reports that show `DateTime` values from the database in various locations. Regardless of how the formatting is done (no formatting at all, using "d" in the `Format` property, or using `FormatDateTime` with any of the DateFormat enumeration values), it always appears to format the DateTime with the en-US culture rather than the system date and number formatting culture.

I've validated that `CurrentCulture` is as expected. The report language is set to "Default". The `Language` tag is not even present in the .rdlc file. If I change the report language then it appears to reflect the formatting for that culture regardless of the system culture.

Is there a way either to render the report with the current system culture, or programmatically modify the language of the report based upon the culture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that "Default" as a Language setting doesn't do much. In order to pick up the user's current culture, Language has to be specified as the expression "=User.Language" (this also needs to be set on all subreports, as the value doesn't propagate or inherit).

Credit to Chris May in his [blog article on the subject](http://www.chrismay.org/2006/10/09/Make+Use+Of+Culture+In+SQL+Reporting+Services+Local+Reports.aspx).